# Where are the result and facet summaries for a search api view?

Tags: 7, search

I had a solr search api search view all set up and working with the results showing properly, and an area at the top showing how many results had been found and what facets were applied with little links to cancel those filters.

Unfortunately I had to rebuild the entire thing because of a change in the content types in use.

Now I cannot figure out how to get that results/facets summary bar back.  How do I get that?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems like it should be the current search block.  I still haven't managed to get it to work yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was the Current Search Block which is a module that comes with facet api.  It wasn't showing up for me because I needed to go into the block configuration, and update what search page it should appear on.